# How to call log out api on browser close or tab close in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, logout, onbeforeunload

When I close browser or tab it should call log out api.
can anybody suggest any solution on it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect browser or tab closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing)

Answer (score 1):

This is an illustration that I came about, link included but it does not factor in the refresh part so still figuring that out.

```
import {useEffect} from 'react';

const App = () => {

  let logOut = () => {
    localStorage.clear();
    navigate('/login')
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleTabClose = event => {
      event.preventDefault();

      console.log('beforeunload event triggered');

      return (event.returnValue = 'Are you sure you want to exit?');
    };

    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleTabClose);

    return () => {
    logOut()
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleTabClose);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>hello world</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-handle-tab-close-event][1]

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the logout API right before your component unmounts.

For functional components, the clean up function is the place:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            // Logout logic goes here
        }
    }, []);
}
```

For class-based components, it's the `componentWillUnmount()` function:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    componentWillUnmount() {
        // Logout logic goes here
    }
}
```

But wait, that will trigger the logout every time the user moves away from the page, even without closing the browser/tab. For that, you could make use of a state variable, and handle outbound navigations based on its value.

For example, create an `isOnlineNav` state variable that is `false` by default, and you set it to `true` whenever the user moves away by interacting with the app (link clicks, navigation, form submission, redirects, etc.). When the user closes the browser tab, the value remains `false`, and you could use the state to trigger logout.

Example in a functional component:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {

    const [isOnlineNav, setIsOnlineNav] = useState(false);

    const goHome = () => {
        setIsOnlineNav(true);
        window.location = "/";
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            if (!isOnlineNav) {
                // Logout logic goes here
            }
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <button onClick={goHome}>Go Home</button>
    )
}
```

It could cause unexpected bugs if you're not careful. Below are at least two of those possible scenarios.

1. You need to cover all in-app ways that your user could navigate away
   from this page.
2. Some otherwise straightforward ways of navigation will get a little more complicated (e.g.: You won't be able to use a `<Link>` or `<a>` tag with a direct path to go to).

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above methods and they all have some issues. For example, "beforeunload" listener calls every time when the user navigates to another screen but we only want to call it on the tab close. Here's how I fixed it.

```
1- First store your token in sessionStorage

   sessionStorage.setItem("logged", true);


2- Now you can check if the logged variable value is false then you can call the logout function.

 const isLogged = sessionStorage.getItem("logged");

 useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLogged) {
        dispatch(logout());
    }
   }, []);
```